# replace slashes in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a local file path containing "\" and I need to change all occurrences to "/" for a remote file path.

I have tried

```
myString.replace("\","/")
```

and

```
myString.replace(Convert.ToChar(92), Convert.ToChar(47))
```

Both seem to leave the "\" in tact..

**Answer:**

```
NewString = myString.replace("\","/")
```

The problem was that I was not assigning it to a variable. Escaping the slash actually made it fail, in vb.net at least.

Comment: You don't want to replace slashes but BACKSLASHES.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings are immutable. The `Replace` method returns a new string rather than affecting the current string, therefore you need to capture the result in a variable. If you're using VB.NET there's no need to escape the backslash, however in C# it must be escaped by using 2 of them.

VB.NET (no escaping needed):

```
myString = myString.Replace("\","/")
```

C# (backslash escaped):

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\","/");
```

I assume you're using VB.NET since you don't include a semicolon, didn't escape the backslash and due to the casing of the replace method used.

Comment: You are the man... Although, there was no need to escape the backslash. simply Replace("\","/")

Comment: @cinqoTimo if you're using VB.NET there's no need to escape it, unlike C#. I'll update to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

`\` has to be escaped, by prefixing it with another `\` or by turning the complete string into an native string by prefixing the string with `@`. Furthermore, myString.replace does not alter myString (strings are immutable, i.e. cannot be changed), so you need to assign the value to see the result.

Use

```
string myNewString = myString.replace("\\","/")
```

or

```
string myNewString = mmyString.replace(@"\","/")
```

or

```
string myNewString = mmyString.replace('\\','/')
```

Comment: the "\" is a special character, so you have to escape it using "\"

Comment: You only need to escape in C~ - VB.Net, which appears to be the language being used, doesn't require this.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `\`:

```
myString.replace("\\","/")
```

Or use a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx) (C#):

```
myString.replace(@"\","/")
```

Or use the overload that uses `char`s:

```
myString.replace('\','/')
```

Comment: Wrong direction of the slash in the first line ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `back slash (\)` with an **extra** `back slash (\\)` , try this:

```
myString.replace("\\","/")
```