# Change C:\Folder\File to C:\\Folder\\file

Tags: vb.net, text, format, string-formatting

I am fiddling around with the following code. However, I need the file name restructured from the `C:\MY FOLDER\MY FILE` format to the `C:\\MY FOLDER\\MY FILE` format. How can I do this?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_Clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        'OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
        'OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"

        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            ''insert code to read the file data
            strm.Close()
            'MessageBox.Show("file closed")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim FILEx As String = "C:\FILEPATH.txt"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILEx) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILEx, False)
            objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
`code`
```

The code is rough.I am just testing some things out.

Comment: What does the question have to do with the code?  Why are you doubling the \'s?   What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (VB, not C#, booh :p)

If you're writing a explicit string like "C:\FILEPATH.txt" you need to double up the \ yourself. Otherwise VB will think \F is a special character. That or preceed the string with a @.

So:

```
"C:\\FILEPATH.txt"
```

or

```
@"C:\FILEPATH.txt"
```

Internally VB will only see a single \
So if, say, you're getting the path from a textbox you don't need to double the backslashes.

**EDIT**

Ok, so according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351494/replace-slashes-in-net) VB.NET actually does indeed not escape backslashes. Consider my answer useless then. (Although perhaps I educated some C-sharper out there... ? (I know I know, I'm grasping here :p)

Comment: IIRC, this isn't correct. I remember pulling my hair out for hours in VB.NET going `"blah blah blah \n"`, only to realize that it does not expand backslash escapes. Can someone check this quickly? (Don't have a good visual studio install available ATM..)